# Robot Framework - Dictionary Variables

Tags: selenium, dictionary, robotframework

I'm trying to create dynamic dictionary variables. Let's say I have `&{Day_Dropdown_Value}` and it has variables as `UK=li:nth-of-type(5)` and `AU=div:nth-of-type(7)`. I can use this dictionary variables by country parameter like `&{Day_Dropdown_Value}[${COUNTRY}]`. But actually I want to make dictionary's variables as dynamic like `UK=li:nth-of-type(${value})`. Is there any solution for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer to Burak's comments. You need to use Get From Dictionary to fetch value

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Dict
    ${Day_Dropdown_Value}=    Create Dictionary
    Set To Dictionary         ${Day_Dropdown_Value}    AU=7
    Set To Dictionary         ${Day_Dropdown_Value}    UK=5
    ${value}=                 Get From Dictionary    ${Day_Dropdown_Value}    UK
    Log                       li:nth-of-type(${value})
```

Comment: It's a kind of solution of my question but actually I want to call the ${value} variable as dynamically. I want to create a dictionary as 
'${c}= Create Dictionary country=UK value=5' and I want to call 'li:nth-of-type(${value})' with '${c}' dictionary's value. But it gives an error because of '${value}' not defined as variable.On the other hand If I create a '${value}' variable in resoruce, 'li:nth-of-type(${value})' is using '${value}' that is defined in resoruces file not the dictionary value.

Comment: I will update my answer. You need to use Get From Dictionary to get correct value